# Is saving an entity with a component collection supposed to do a SQL DELETE then INSERT using NHibernate?

Tags: sql, nhibernate, components, crud

I have an entity, `TrackLog` that has a component collection of `TrackPoints`. I create a new `TrackLog` and add some `Trackpoints` to it and save it to the DB.

When I grab my `TrackLog` again and add a new `TrackPoint`, instead of doing one SQL INSERT like I expect, it's doing a DELETE on all the `TrackPoints` associated with the `TrackLog` and then re-adding every `TrackPoint` that's in the collection.

This is the output from NHProf:

```
UPDATE TrackLog SET Version = 2 etc...
DELETE FROM TrackPoints WHERE TrackLog_Id = '80cc1e0d' etc...
INSERT INTO TrackPoints etc..
INSERT INTO TrackPoints etc...
INSERT INTO TrackPoints etc...
```

My question is, is this normal behavior for a component collection? This happens as well for my enum collections. If this is not normal behavior, how do I modify my mappings so that it exhibits the correct behavior (only one INSERT for the `TrackPoint` I added)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal.

To avoid it, declare your collection as a `set` instead of a `bag` (and use compatible types) if your use case supports it (i.e. there can't be two trackpoints with the same data)

Comment: Thanks, I just came to the same conclusion myself. Another thing to keep in mind is that your components must override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`, or else performance is even worse (rather than one DELETE statement, it generates a DELETE for each item, then does an INSERT for each again).

Comment: Yes, that's correct and it makes sense because components don't have an identifier, so that's the only way (for NH) to tell them apart.